# Does Kustomize require you specify an entire resource to change one value?

Tags: kustomize

I'd understood that Kustomize would be the solution to my Kubernetes configuration management needs where, for example, if I want maxReplicas for a resource to be 3 on my dev and test environments but 7 in production, I could do that easily. I imagined there'd be a base file, and then an overlay file that would respecify just the values needing changing. My goal is that if I have multiple configurations (configurations? nodes? clusters? I'm still having trouble with K8s terminology. I mean dev, test, prod.), any time a value common to all of them needed changing, I could change it in one place, the base configuration, instead of in three different config files. Essentially, just as in programming, I want to factor out what's common to all the environments.

But I'm looking at https://www.densify.com/kubernetes-tools/kustomize/ and getting a different impression. Here, the dev version of an hpa.yml file is only meant to change the values of maxReplicas and averageUtilization. So I'd thought the overlay would look as follows, in the same way that, in a .NET Core application, appsettings.dev.json only needs to specify the settings from appsettings.json that it's overriding:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: frontend-deployment-hpa
spec:
  maxReplicas: 2
    target:
      averageUtilization: 90
```

instead of the whole definition that's in the example given. So, if I started with all instances having minReplicas = 1 and I wanted to change it to 3 for all of them, I'd have make that change in every overlay instead of just in the base.

Is this correct? If so, is there a tool that will allow configuration management to work as *I'm* looking to have it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this correct?

No.

Kustomize does not require to specify the entire resource in order to change a single value; the entire point of Kustomize is its ability to transform manifests through patches and other mechanisms to produce the desired output.

For example, assume the following layout:

```
.
├── base
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   └── kustomization.yaml
└── overlays
    ├── dev
    │   └── kustomization.yaml
    └── prod
        └── kustomization.yaml
```

In `base/deployment.yaml` we have:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: web
          image: docker.io/traefik/whoami:latest
```

And in `base/kustomization.yaml` we have:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
commonLabels:
  app: kustomize-demo

resources:
- deployment.yaml
```

---

If in my `dev` environment I want to keep `replicas: 1`, I would create `overlays/dev/kustomization.yaml` like this:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- ../../base
```

This simply includes the resources from `base` verbatim.

On the other hand, if in my production environment I want to run with three replicas, I would patch the Deployment resource in `overlays/prod/kustomization.yaml` like this:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- ../../base

patches:
  - patch: |
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      kind: Deployment
      metadata:
        name: demo
      spec:
        replicas: 3
```

This type of patch is called a "strategic merge patch"; you can also apply changes using "JSONPatch" patches. That might look like:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- ../../base

patches:
  - target:
      kind: Deployment
      name: demo
    patch: |
      - op: replace
        path: /spec/replicas
        value: 3
```

The kustomize documentation has a variety of examples of patching and other [transformations](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/transformerconfigs/README.md). For example, the `commonLabels` directive I show in `base/kustomization.yaml` uses the labels transformer to produce this output:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kustomize-demo
  name: demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kustomize-demo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kustomize-demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker.io/traefik/whoami:latest
        name: web
```

Notice how the labels defined in `commonLabels` have been applied both to:

1. The top-level /metadata/labels element
2. The /spec/selector/matchLabels element
3. The /spec/template/metdata/labels element